# How to Add Two Columns of DataFrame and Rename it with Prefix Name using bash

Tags: python, linux, bash, terminal

```
The original Data looks like

ID,kgp11274425_A,kgp11274425_HET,kgp5732633_C,kgp5732633_HET,rs707_G,rs707_HET,kgp75_T,kgp75_HET
1,C,T,G,T,C,A,0,0
2,C,C,T,G,A,A,G,T
3,A,A,G,G,C,G,A,A
4,G,G,C,C,A,A,T,A

Desired Output:

ID,kgp11274425,kgp5732633,rs707,kgp75
1,CT,GT,CA,00
2,CC,TG,AA,GT
3,AA,GG,CG,AA
4,GG,CC,AA,TA

I was able to accomplish this using the following Python Script

sep = '_'
unique_cols = pd.Index(map(lambda x : x.split(sep, 1)[0], df.columns)).unique()

results = []
columns = []
for col in unique_cols:
    my_cols = [x for x in df.columns if x.startswith(col)]
    results.append(df[my_cols].sum(axis=1).values)
    columns.append(col)

new_df = pd.DataFrame(results).T
new_df.columns = columns
```

But this time I got 522rows & 5311137cols (5GB) data, Python is not able to read the file. So I need to run the same python logic using bash commands, new to bash please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Input:

```
$ cat raw.dat
ID,kgp11274425_A,kgp11274425_HET,kgp5732633_C,kgp5732633_HET,rs707_G,rs707_HET,kgp75_T,kgp75_HET
1,C,T,G,T,C,A,0,0
2,C,C,T,G,A,A,G,T
3,A,A,G,G,C,G,A,A
4,G,G,C,C,A,A,T,A
```

One `awk` idea:

```
awk -F, '
{ printf $1                                                # print 1st column
  for (i=2;i<=NF;i=i+2) {                                  # process columns 2 at a time
      if (FNR==1)                                          # 1st row? then ...
         printf "%s%s", FS, substr($i,1,index($i,"_")-1)   # print ith column sans the '_xxxx' suffix
      else
         printf "%s%s%s", FS, $i, $(i+1)                   # print the (i)th and (i+1)th columns
  }
  print ""
}
' raw.dat
```

This generates:

```
ID,kgp11274425,kgp5732633,rs707,kgp75
1,CT,GT,CA,00
2,CC,TG,AA,GT
3,AA,GG,CG,AA
4,GG,CC,AA,TA
```

**NOTE:** OP's desired output does not appear to be single-space delimited, nor tab delimited, so I've opted for a single space; OP can modify the `printf` format strings to accomplish the desired formatting

Comment: Hello @markp-fuso, I have updated the data format can you please update the command

Comment: I have tried to modify `printf` but not working

Comment: @RajuNatha you changed the format of the input data so you need to tell `awk` the new format ... in this case tell `awk` the new column delimiter is a comma (`,`); then add the comma to the `printf` calls, too; answer has been updated

Answer (score -2):

The basic approach is to kinda emulate what FPAT does, but in a more portable fashion - this code has been tested and confirmed working on `gawk 5.1.1`, including flags `-ce/-Pe`, `mawk 1.3.4`, `mawk 1.9.9.6`, and `macOS 12.3 nawk`.

```
ID, kgp11274425     kgp5732633      rs707       kgp75       
1       CT            GT              CA       00
2       CC            TG              AA       GT
3       AA            GG              CG       AA
4       GG            CC              AA       TA

[mng]awk 'BEGIN {

    FS = "[_][^_]+[_][^,]+[,]?[ " (substr(\
   OFS = "\t\t", _+=_=_~_))  "]*"

    print $( (getline) < -(NF=NF) )

    __ = (__="[^ \t]+") substr(_=substr(___="&\6\3",_) \
               "[ \t]+",  index(_, "[") ) __ "|_"
    FS = "^$"

 } gsub(__,___) + gsub(_,"")' datafile.txt
```

1. By using `regex`, it avoids having to manually cycle through the
   fields, even when 2-fields at a time. `\6\3` (`ACK + ETX`) is just
   an `ASCII-only SEP` choice I prefer over `SUBSEP` (`\034`) or the
   null-byte (`\0`).
2. A 2nd advantage is that by having separate and independent logic
   that attempts to emulate `FPAT`, `FS` can be set directly to `^$`,
   as the rationale for splitting up individual fields is no
   longer applicable ...

   . . . which, hopefully, could help move things along, since OP did mention `500K+` columns.

- The caveat of this solution is that it doesn't attempt to have everything line up in a perfect manner, using `\t\t` 2 horizontal tabs as a crude solution.

Synthetic `5GB` file benchmark :  `1 min 14 secs` for `5.12GB` file, with read-in throughput rate of `70.5 MB/s`

```
     out9: 2.54GiB 0:01:14 [34.9MiB/s] [34.9MiB/s]
           [====================================>] 102%
      in0: 5.12GiB 0:01:14 [70.5MiB/s] [70.5MiB/s]
           [====================================>] 100%            
( pvE 0.1 in0 < testcase_dna_002.txt | gawk -be ; )  

  73.44s user 2.20s system 101% cpu 1:14.37 total

nice pv -pteba -i 0.25 -r --size='2540m' -cN out9 > /dev/null  0.24s 

 user 0.73s system 1% cpu 1:14.37 total
```